# Compute Shannon entropy between every row of a large, sparse matrix

Tags: r, distance-functions, entropy, similarities, sparse

I have a sparse, binary matrix of user (rows) and items (columns).  Each element of this matrix is either 0 or 1:

```
require(Matrix)
set.seed(42)
rows <- 10
cols <- 2
non_zero <- 20
x <-  sparseMatrix(i = sample(1:rows, non_zero, replace=TRUE),
                   j = sample(1:cols, non_zero, replace=TRUE),
                   x=1)
colnames(x) <- letters[1:ncol(x)]
x <- sign(x)
print(x)
10 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
      a b
 [1,] . .
 [2,] 1 1
 [3,] . 1
 [4,] . .
 [5,] 1 1
 [6,] . 1
 [7,] 1 .
 [8,] 1 1
 [9,] . 1
[10,] 1 1
```

(In reality I have about 1e7 row, 1e6 columns and about 1e8 elements in this matrix)

I would like to compute Shannon Entropy between every column of this Matrix ([as described here](http://www.slideshare.net/larsga/using-the-search-engine-as-recommendation-engine)).  I would like to do this using [sparse matrix operations](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/index.html), as using dense matrix operations will be extremely inefficient on a matrix of this size.

It's pretty easy to calculate the various frequencies tables need, e.g.:

A and B counts:

```
a_and_b <- crossprod(x)
print(a_and_b)
2 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"
  a b
a 5 4
b 4 7
```

B, not A counts and A, not B counts:

```
b_not_a <- crossprod(sign(a_and_b), Diagonal(x=diag(a_and_b)))
a_not_b <- t(b_not_a)

a_not_b <- a_not_b - a_and_b
b_not_a <- b_not_a - a_and_b

print(a_not_b)
2 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
  a b
a 0 1
b 3 0

print(b_not_a)
2 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
  a b
a 0 3
b 1 0
```

And finally, not A not B counts:

```
not_a_b <- crossprod(
  sign(a_and_b), 
  Diagonal(n=ncol(a_and_b), x=nrow(x))
  ) - a_not_b - b_not_a - a_and_b
print(not_a_b)
2 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
  a b
a 5 2
b 2 3
```

I can compute these 4 contingency matrices (A and B, A not B, B not A, not A and not B) extremely fast, even on huge matrices.  How can I use them to calculate the Shannon entropy between each item (column) of my original matrix `x`?

The final output should look something like this:

```
     a    b
a 0.43 0.89
b 0.96 0.64
```